# How to legally download Windows 7 ISO for MSDN license?

Tags: windows-7, windows, iso-image

I have gone through similar topics and I think my case is not a duplicate.

Some 3 years ago, I had purchased a key for Windows 7 Professional from MSDN subscription. It worked fine and I've been getting Windows updates as necessary.

Now my system has become so slow that I'm thinking of re-installing Windows. I have the key with which I had activated Windows at that time. But I've been having a hard time trying to get an ISO.

I came across [Microsoft Software Recovery](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-recovery) but as expected, my product key was found to be invalid there.

Does that mean I can never re-install my Windows and continue with my same product key ever? Is there is no provision for OEM/MSDN licenses?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN License you say? You can download an ISO from here:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/#ProductFamilyId=0&Languages=en&ProductFamilyIds=350&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0

An alternative download venue is here:

- https://www.pcsteps.com/45-download-windows-7-iso-legally-free-digital-river/

Comment: The Digital River method has not been possible for over a year.

Comment: @Ramhound Just because there is the word "digital river" in my URL doesn't mean that's reason I am listing it.

Comment: I can't confirm what the website says, because it the link, doesn't work for me.  It doesn't really matter, Microsoft closed the Digital River method, awhile ago.

Comment: @Ramhound Too bad. The website offers a way download ISOs once offered by Digital River and then verify their authenticity against MSDN hashes. Also the link explains why OP couldn't get an ISO from MSR.

Comment: The German digital river mirror has already been documented in an answer to the duplicate

Comment: @Ramhound You mean the post by harrymc? Oh, he posted my second URL too.

Comment: The first link says "Unable to Service Request" now...